# JavaFx volume slider is not changing the volume. The volume stays the same

Tags: javafx

So, for my class project I am making a game. I want to add a volume slider to change the music volume. I am very stuck here. Please help me.

I was following tutorial, and I was able to display it on the scree. But, the volume doesn't change, even though I slide the bar. Can somebody give me advice? Thank you.

```
private Scene createOptionScene() {
        String path = "E:\\All Computer Science Materials\\Java 240 Project\\PrinceFX\\Music\\"
                + songs.getSong(1) + ".mp3";
        Media media = new Media(new File(path).toURI().toString());
        currentPlay = new AudioClip(media.getSource());
        currentPlay.setCycleCount(MediaPlayer.INDEFINITE);
        currentPlay.play();


    // Volume Control
    volumeSlider.setValue(currentPlay.getVolume() * 100);
    volumeSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new InvalidationListener() {
        @Override
        public void invalidated(Observable observable) {
            currentPlay.setVolume(volumeSlider.getValue() / 100);
        }
    });

    HBox temp = new HBox();
    temp.getChildren().addAll(volumeSlider);
    temp.setTranslateX(850);
    temp.setTranslateY(410);
    volumeSlider.setMinWidth(300);



    Image image = new Image(new File("E:\\All Computer Science Materials\\" +
            "Java 240 Project\\PrinceFX\\image\\" + picture.getImage(2) + ".png").toURI().toString());
    //Setting the image view
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);

    //Setting the position of the image
    imageView.setX(0);
    imageView.setY(0);
    //setting the fit height and width of the image view
    imageView.setFitHeight(primaryScreenBounds.getHeight());
    imageView.setFitWidth(primaryScreenBounds.getWidth());
    //Setting the preserve ratio of the image view
    imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

    Label labelOption = new Label();
    Button goBack = new Button("Go Back to Main");
    goBack.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            currentPlay.stop();
            sceneStart = createStartScene();
            stageOne.setScene(sceneStart);
        }
    });

    // Button to the main page.
    HBox layoutOp = new HBox(15);
    layoutOp.getChildren().addAll(labelOption, goBack);

    // Button coordinate.
    layoutOp.setTranslateX(1400);
    layoutOp.setTranslateY(750);

    Group gOption = new Group(imageView, layoutOp, temp);
    return new Scene(gOption, 200, 200);
}
```

Comment: This seem to be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479821/javafx-mediaplayer-volume-trouble-why-the-volume-of-mediaplayer-do-not-chang

Comment: pdem. I still don't get it.

Comment: You have added an `InvalidationListener` to your `valueProperty` variable. This is not the good one. You have to use a `ChangeListener`.

Comment: Hi Pagbo, thank you for the advice. However,         volumeSlider.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observableValue, Number number, Number t1) {
                currentPlay.setVolume(volumeSlider.getValue() / 100);
            }
        });                                                                                                                     is still not working.

Comment: @BamosMoha Use the `number` variable from your `ChangeListener`. It matches with the new value of your slider (t1 is the old/previous value of your slider).